# Is there a list widget in Pharo that let's the user visually order the list items?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

Is there a list widget in Pharo that let's the user visually order the list items by dragging and dropping, so that the new order of items is propageted to the OrderedCollection represented by the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no ready made widget. There are however applications that provide such functionality, you could look at their source code.

For example in OmniBrowser the class categories can be reordered by drag and drop. And the refactoring extension contains a dialog implementation in `OBMethodNameEditor` that provides a similar re-ordering functionality for method arguments.